# AWK: Compare fields in two files with multiple fields

Tags: awk

can somebody help me?

**File1:**

```
Red|Circle|123|apple|orange|grapes

Blue|Square|345|apple|banana|blueberry

Red|Triangle|143|strawberry|orange|grapes
```

**File2:**

```
123|Square|banana|blueberry

123|Triangle|strawberry|grapes

347|Circle|orange|strawberry
```

**Output:**

```
Red|Circle|123|apple|orange|grapes|Square|banana|blueberry

Red|Circle|123|apple|orange|grapes|Triangle|strawberry|grapes
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: I have no idea how you arrive at that output. Why are you making us guess?

Comment: sorry. I need to combine the 2 files wherein field 3 of file1 and field 1 of file2 matches. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below `awk` should get you started:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  FS = "|"
 }
NR == FNR {
# while reading the 1st file
# store its records in the array f
f[$3] = $0
  next
 }
$1 in f {
# when match is found
# print all values
print f[$1], $0>   }' file1 file2


Red|Circle|123|apple|orange|grapes 123|Square|banana|blueberry

Red|Circle|123|apple|orange|grapes 123|Triangle|strawberry|grapes
```